# How to add columns date_created and date_updated to Snowflake database?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am attempting to add a date_created column and a date_updated column to a table in my Snowflake database.

I want to do something along the lines of:

```
  ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN date_created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
  ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN date_updated timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

I have tried many variations of this and I have not found what I am looking for in their documentation. I feel that this should be simple to do. However, I have not been able to successfully get these columns added to my table. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: As of a couple years ago, I don't think this was possible on Snowflake. One bandaide was adding the column, then updating the column with a separate statement but I don't think that actually solves the problem. I've seen some people create a new table, which seems crazy but might be the only solution.

Comment: If you think about it, you obviously can’t add a not null column to an existing table as the not null constraint would be violated for all the existing rows. Also, the default value only applies when inserting a record so that doesn’t help here. You have to add the column with nulls allowable, then populate the column for all existing records and then set the column to not null

Comment: @NickW  `If you think about it, you obviously can’t add a not null column to an existing table as the not null constraint would be violated for all the existing rows. Also, the default value only applies when inserting a record so that doesn’t help here` - It is possible to add a NOT NULL column with DEFAULT value to a non-empty table: [ALTER TABLE tab ADD COLUMN i INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3LNo.png)  It is not possible to use non-constant or datetime literals in this context.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN date_created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

The query should be sufficient.

Reference to Snowflake documentation : [Alter Table - Snowflake](https://web.archive.org/web/20231023171322/https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table)

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried that. It does not work, it gives an error message saying 'Invalid column default expression [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()]'.